# Как прибавлять числа из списка до определённого значения?

Tags: python, list

Я недавно начал изучать свой первый ЯП Python. Появилась такая задача:
например имеется список
`a = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]`
Нужно прибавить эти числа так, что бы получилось число **221**.
Так же нужен вывод тех чисел, что были прибавлены. В данном случае это: *64 64 64 16 8 4 1*. Как это правильно реализовать? Буду благодарен за ответы.

Comment: Так изучение языка предполагает самостоятельное решение задач. Какая польза от готового решения?

Comment: а почему не 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1?

Comment: @user207200, польза такова, что новичок хотя бы примерно поймет, что да как делается. Он постарается понять код другого человека, "прогнав" его через отладчик. Тогда зачем нужны все эти форумы, если " изучение языка предполагает самостоятельное решение задач"? Зачем Вы здесь сидите, ведь опять же - "изучение языка предполагает самостоятельное решение задач"

Comment: @Arbuz да-да, зачем эти ваши вузы если там меня букварю не учат. Этот форум конечно не вуз, но и не ясельная группа детского сада.

Comment: @Alexey Ten, я новичок и на таких форумах ни разу не сидел. Если этот форум только для продвинутых и выше, а новичкам тут не место - то ладно, буду знать.

Comment: Это сообщество для всех. Но оно про _конкретные проблемы, связанные с программированием и алгоритмами_.

Comment: @user207200, я Вас понял. Постараюсь впредь не задавать детских вопросов, а более тщательно (на сколько получится) изучать вопрос. В любом случае спасибо за контакт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если  нет других ограничений, то алгоритм такой:

1. идем от большего значения к меньшему
2. определяем сколько в сумму входит указанных значений
3. вычитаем это кол-во, умноженное на значение, из суммы

вопрос в том, гарантирует ли такой способ решения задачи нахождение результата (потому что задача может сводиться к перебору)

результат не всегда (если он существует) будет оптимальным (минимальное кол-во слагаемых)

Comment: но конкретно в этом наборе чисел (степени двойки) результат точно будет и будет оптимальным

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Теперь хотя бы понятен алгоритм действий. Буду дальше изучать.

Comment: Вообще-то из списка [2,3] таким алгоритмом 4 не получается. Нужен еще механизм "отката", если следующее меньшее число даст "перебор".